# Angular Material's md-checkbox - all checkboxes check when using ng-model.

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The radio choice, styled as a checkbox, works great like this with no issues:

```
  <div ng-repeat="choice in regions| orderBy: 'description'">
    <input type="radio"
      value="{{choice.name}}"
      name="regionRadio"
      ng-model="radio.region">
    {{choice.description}}
  </div>

input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
  -moz-appearance: checkbox; 
  -ms-appearance: checkbox;  
}
```

However, if I want to use Angular Materials `md-checkbox`:

```
  <div ng-repeat="choice in regions| orderBy: 'description'">
    <md-checkbox type="radio"
      value="{{choice.name}}"
      ng-model="radio.region">
    {{choice.description}}
    </md-checkbox>
  </div>
```

It does not handle the `ng-model` well. When just one checkbox is selected, all the checkboxes become selected(checked).

Any suggestions how to make `md-checkbox` work in the same manner with `ng-model` as before?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. `md-checkbox` does not have the attribute `type` [according to the docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdCheckbox). You should really use `md-radio-group` to stay within AM best practice.

I have created an example with `md-checkbox` and `md-radio-group` - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/MbVoML?editors=1010#0)

Clicking a checkbox does not select all the checkboxes but you can select more than one checkbox. It's quite easy to write some code to make the checkboxes act like radio buttons though.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <p>Checkbox</p>
  <div ng-repeat="choice in regions| orderBy: 'description'">
    <md-checkbox type="radio"
                 value="{{choice.name}}"
                 ng-model="radio.region">
      {{choice.description}}
    </md-checkbox>
  </div>
  <p>{{radio.region}}</p>

  <p>Radio Group</p>
  <md-radio-group ng-model="newradio.region">
    <md-radio-button ng-repeat="choice in regions| orderBy: 'description'" value="{{choice.name}}" class="md-primary">{{choice.description}}</md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
  <p>{{newradio.region}}</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.regions = [
    {name: "sky", description: "The sky"},
    {name: "sea", description: "The sea"},
    {name: "land", description: "The land"},
    {name: "water", description: "The water"}
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a shot in the dark and assume you had the same (or very similar) issue as me. I was stunned to search and find this issue was unique to you and me until I started to look into my parent containers and realized my mistake.

My issue was that I included my md-checkbox INSIDE an md-list-item. Upon clicking anywhere in that md-list-item, my md-checkbox toggled. In retrospect, I should have noticed sooner with the giveaway ripple effect.

The md-checkbox directive is one of the proxied elements that gets triggered when clicking inside an md-list-item. Adding the class "md-no-proxy" to the md-list-item element removes this (and the ripple) effect.*

If you were not using a parent md-list-item element, I suggest looking into whether or not any of your parent containers/directives proxies an ng-click in it's children elements.

*Source:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdListItem